# Python while loop to get multiple inputs. Two techniques - cases when fail?

Tags: python, input, while-loop

Re-asking, re-wording, this since first time got closed for being an opinion. Thanks to deceze and Thierry for getting in thoughts before closed.

Python:   Both code samples below use a while loop to allow multiple inputs. So far both have worked for me. For the future, what situations would create failures in one technique vs. the other?

```
print( "Technique #1 - *while True:*")
name_in = ''
while True:  
    name_in = input('enter name or "done"')
    if name_in=='done': break
    print(name_in) #do some task


print( " Technique #2 - *while expression:*")
name_in = input('enter name or "done"')  # first time
while name_in != 'done': 
    print(name_in) #do some task
    name_in = input('enter name or "done"') #subsequents
```

Comment: Both are essentially identical. In one case you have only one `input()`, which makes it easier if you want to change the input prompt, but otherwise there's absolutely no difference. Can you clarify what you mean by _" For the future, what situations would create failures"_? Do you expect one way to stop working because of changes to Python in the future?

Comment: Pranav: thanks. Good point on dup prompt is bad. Yes, I'm 'worried' about future. Trying to think ahead of anything that might go wrong. I'm hoping other coder's experience might point to a potential problem. Thanks for sharing your expertise.

Comment: Well this is fairly basic flow control, so don't expect for it to change significantly in the future. Both methods are pretty future-proof IMO. Use the one that floats your boat.

Answer (score 2):

Functionally the two approaches should be the same; I don't think there's any input you can give that will cause them to behave differently.

The main difference is that technique #2 involves code duplication (you had to copy and paste the input statement), which is bad because if you ever need to change the prompt now you need to change it in two places.

You can slightly shorten the code for technique #1 by not initializing `name_in` before the loop, since it's never used before you assign it within the loop body.

Comment: Samwise:  good point: duplicate prompt is bad.  But how else to avoid the entry of 'done' being processed in tasks? Needs another if before task to check if input is 'done'

Comment: Yes; your `break` in technique 1 already accomplishes that.

Answer (score 2):

Python 3.8 introduced the `walrus operator` `:=`

```
# Loop-and-a-half (see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#capturing-condition-values)
while (name_in := input('enter name or "done"')) != "done":
    print(name_in)
```

isn't it a beauty?

Comment: ack:  Sent me to research. Thanks. Any case you can think of where result undesirable?

Comment: GAS: None I can think of - it is short, it is clean, it is very pythonic. I use it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use something similar to this:

```
name_in = ''
while name_in != "something":
    name_in = input('enter name or "something"')
print(n_name)
```

Comment: Arin: Thanks, One thought: that would leave "done' processed by the tasks, right? So would need if to exclude from task?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you asked me i'm sorry if it's just me but if you refer to like having to print the name_in after that, yes

Comment: Sorry for that but I am new to stack overflow and I put backticks cuz that's how I learned from discord, thanks btw

Comment: This doesn't answer the question! OP knows they can use something like this because _that's what 'Technique #2' is!_

Comment: Well I am still learning english so i'm sorry if this doesn't answer the question